# Python 2 and Python 3 conversion issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to convert a small python2 script into python3. The line

```
values += [0] * ((time + len(frames)) - len(values))
```

works perfectly in python2, but give me this error message in python3:

```
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I suspect your real problem is elsewhere in the code, I would guess with the `time` variable. In neither Python 2 nor Python 3 can you multiply a list by a float. It would help to understand the context a bit better.

Comment: You need to show more details about your code